# how can I solve this "no launch history" in android

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have problem with avd , I can't run my application in avd .

when a press run as is display me "no launch history" .

Comment: Are you launching from snapshot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your AVD. Remove the checkmark against `Snapshot`. Save and start AVD again.

You can always edit your AVD afterwards and set the checkmark to save on launch time on subsequent uses.

Comment: @user3443229 That's good. :) Please consider accepting this answer then. All you have to do is click the check-mark (its to the left of 0) to indicate that this answer worked.